# Add numbers to the beginning of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of list, say X, that looks like this

```
X_train = [[4,3,1,5], [3,1,6,2], [5,0,49,4], ... , [3,57,3,3]]
```

I wrote this piece of code

```
for x in range(0,len(X_train)):
    X_train[x].insert(0, x+1)
```

For each list in X this code inserts the index value of the list + 1 to the beginning of the list. That is, running

```
for x in range(0,len(X_train)):
    X_train[x].insert(0, x+1)
print(X)
```

will produce the following output

```
[[1,4,1,5],[2,3,1,6,2],[3,5,0,49,4],...,[n,3,57,3,3]]
```

where n is the number of lists in X.

**Question:** Is there a faster way to do this? I would like to be able to do this for very large lists, e.g. list with millions of sublists (if that's possible).

Comment: Inserting at the beginning of a list is O(n). If you can control the nested data strcuture you should opt for sth that has O(1) operation on both ends, like `collections.deque`.

Comment: If that is the input you have and the output you want, the answer is no. `list` behaves that way. If you want to significantly improve it, you should (a) look to use a different data structure to start from, or (b) check if you really need that exact output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is faster in my testing:

```
X = [[n, *l] for n, l in enumerate(X, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the standard `insert` method in Python has a time complexity of O(n). Given your current implementation, your algo would have a time complexity of O(m x n) where m is the number of sublists and n is the number of elements in the sublists (I assume here that the number of sublist elements is always the same).

You could use [blist](https://pypi.org/project/blist/) instead of the standard lists which has a time complexity of O(log n) for insertions. This means the total time reduces to O(m x log n). It's not that much of an improvement, though.